# How do you run Eclipse IDE for C/C++ from the command line (I already installed it)

Tags: c++, c, eclipse, ide, eclipse-cdt

I used

```
sudo apt-get install eclipse eclipse-cdt g++
```

to install eclipse for c/c++, but I don't know what command runs it.

Comment: have you tryed writing eclipse in terminal

Comment: When I just type eclipse it pulls the java version of eclipse not the c version

Answer (score 1):

Try the following in your terminal:

`$ eclipse`

You may also be interested in various command-line flags or parameters you can pass to Eclipse. The [documentation](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Frunning_eclipse.htm) does a good job at explaining these.

For example, with the `-nosplash` flag, Eclipse will start without showing a splash screen

`$ eclipse -nosplash`

These flags may also be helpful when writing scripts or using a custom Java VM when launching Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

just write `eclipse` in terminal.

Comment: When I just type eclipse it pulls the java version of eclipse not the c version – dark 49 mins ago   delete